# Remove crossed results in SQL SELECT

Tags: sql, database, select

I'm joining two instances of the same table to see the records that matches the same serial number and date, but with different ID's. The purpose is to identify conflicts. My query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  t1.id,
  t1.status,
  t1.date,
  t1.serial,
  t2.id_2,
  t2.status_2,
  t2.date_2,
  t2.serial_2
  FROM table AS t1 INNER JOIN table AS t2 ON t1.serial = t2.serial_2
  WHERE t1.date = t2.date_2 AND t1.id <> t2.id_2
  ORDER BY t1.date, t1.id;
```

This query results in something like:

| id | status | date | serial | id_2 | status_2 | date_2 | serial_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | VALID | 01/13/2021 | 0001 | 02 | VALID | 01/13/2021 | 0001 |
| 02 | VALID | 01/13/2021 | 0001 | 01 | VALID | 01/13/2021 | 0001 |
| 03 | VALID | 02/10/2021 | 0005 | 04 | VALID | 02/10/2021 | 0005 |
| 04 | VALID | 02/10/2021 | 0005 | 03 | VALID | 02/10/2021 | 0005 |
| 05 | VALID | 02/15/2021 | 0007 | 06 | VALID | 02/15/2021 | 0007 |
| 06 | VALID | 02/15/2021 | 0007 | 05 | VALID | 02/15/2021 | 0007 |

The result shows two records for the same conflict. The lines 1 and 2, for example, it is possible to notice that it is the same conflict on 01/13/2021 in relation to serial 0001 related to ID's 01 and 02.

How to eliminate duplications keeping one line for each conflict?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you also _specify_ the expected result, to make things clearer.

Comment: @jarlh, the expected result are lines 1, 3 and 5 (odd ID's). The lines 2, 4 and 6 are refering the same serial number at the same date (the same conflict of the even ID's). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can compare ids to be < instead of <>

```
SELECT 
  t1.id,
  t1.status,
  t1.date,
  t1.serial,
  t2.id_2,
  t2.status_2,
  t2.date_2,
  t2.serial_2
  FROM table AS t1 
  INNER JOIN table AS t2 
      ON t1.serial = t2.serial_2
      AND t1.date = t2.date_2 
      AND t1.id < t2.id_2
  ORDER BY t1.date, t1.id;
```

also probably you don't need `distinct` m depends on how your data looks though .